# Dealing with sensitive information in variable and upload after use

Tags: php, parsing

I'm writing a parser for a digital statement my bank gives out and it works, but say in the case I want to let other people upload their statements to it. What is the best way to deal with the variable data after the script is done?

I'm initially using `file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'])` to get the file's data. After the script is finished, is this temp file deleted? Or do I need to that myself?

For the variables, is `unset()` enough or do I have to go one step further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables are stored in memory, and once the script is finished, the memory is freed and they are destroyed and cannot be recovered. There is no need to call `unset()` on them as this happens implicitly when the script terminates.

The temp files created by file uploads that appear in the `$_FILES` array should be deleted as soon as the script finished execution, but if you want to be doubly sure of this you can call `unlink()` on them.

As long as you don't store sensitive data in `$_SESSION`, cookies, or anything else that explicitly has permanence, you should be alright.

If you do need to hold some data on the server you could encrypt it using, for example, [Mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php).

Comment: Have a +1, my fast(er)-typing friend ;).

Comment: @DexCurl I was just thinking about this and realised that the more important point when doing something like this is to make sure you use a secure server. You need to take whatever precautions you can to ensure that your server cannot be compromised in the first place - firewalls, heavy auth routines, SSL, and absolutely *no* shared boxes.

Answer (score 2):

The temporary file will be deleted eventually. However, AFAIK you cannot really influence this. In order to enfore deletion, use [`unlink()`](http://php.net/unlink/).

Concerning the variables: there is no need to `unset()` them, because they are only stored in RAM and will be destroyed once your scripts execution completes.